# Нужно регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение которое будет отлавливать строки по определенным правилам:

1. На конце не должно быть слеша (/)
2. В строке не должно быть точки (.)
3. В строке не должно быть идущих подряд слеша и знака вопроса (/?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так (пример на JS):

```js
const re = /^(?![^]*\/\?)[^.]*(?<!\/)$/;

console.log(re.test('aaa/'));
console.log(re.test('aa.a'));
console.log(re.test('aa/?a'));
console.log(re.test('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));
```